# Filtering datagrid based on data in rows, Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've search all over today trying to find how to do this, and not being familiar with actionscript is starting to catch up to me. What I would like to accomplish is: I have a list of messages in a Datagrid coming from a dataprovider in another class, which in turn gets them from our Oracle DB. I need to all the user to set a visible state on the message, and then filter that out of the datagrid with the click of a button. I have the check box for hide, and it sets that value into the database. I can't figure out how to get the filterFunction to work with an array collection when the filter parameter is within the row data.

Here is the code

```
public function filterResults():void {

            modelLocator.notification.messageList.filterFunction = filterRows;

            modelLocator.notification.messageList.refresh(); 


        }

        public function filterRows(item:Object):Boolean {
            //return true if row should stay visible
            //return false if it should go away

             var i:int;

            if(showAll == false) {//checks whether this is coming from the hide or show all button
            //Somehow need to interrogate the row data to check if messageVisible is set to true or false

             /* if (showAll == false) {
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
            return false; */ 

        }
        public var showAll:Boolean;

        public function showAllMessages():void{

            showAll = true;
            filterResults();
        }
        public function hideMessages():void{
            showAll = false;
            filterResults();
        }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox>
    <component:EditMessage id="editMessage"  width="930" height="445"/>
    <mx:Panel id="messageListPanel" title="Message History" layout="vertical" width="930" height="196" horizontalAlign="left">

        <mx:DataGrid id="messageDataGrid" dataProvider="{modelLocator.notification.messageList}" 
                     width="910" height="139" enabled="true" mouseEnabled="true" editable="false"
                     rowCount="5" itemClick="{selectMessage()}">

            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Date Created" labelFunction="formatCreateDate" width="60"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="From" dataField="senderEmail" width="100"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Subject" dataField="subject" width="100"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Start Date" labelFunction="formatStartDate" width="60"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="End Date" labelFunction="formatEndDate" width="60" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Date Sent" labelFunction="formatSendDate" width="60" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Sender Netid" dataField="senderNetId" width="50" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Sender Name" dataField="senderName" width="80" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Message" dataField="message" width="100" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Message Id" dataField="id" width="10" />
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>              
    </mx:Panel>                 
</mx:VBox>
<mx:Button id="showMessagesBtn" x="786" y="452" label="Show All Messages" click="showAllMessages()"/>
<mx:Button id="hideMessagesBtn" x="665" y="452" label="Hide Messages" click="hideMessages()" />
```

I found a tutorial on doing this with incoming text here http://franto.com/filter-results-in-datagrid-flex-tutorial/, but cannot figure out the above mentioned problem, this really can't be that difficult, can it?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Your filter function does not return true or false based on an item property. You want to filter data in the dataProvider which has messageVisible set to true?

Comment: Check out this link : http://www.iwobanas.com/2009/06/datagrid-with-client-side-filtering-and-searching/ . I find it pretty awesome both from a learning perspective and as a component :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

item is an element of the dataprovider the method is called for each element in the dataprovider and flags the item for inclusion in length and iteration.

```
       public function filterResults():void {

            modelLocator.notification.messageList.filterFunction = filterRows;

            modelLocator.notification.messageList.refresh(); 


        }

        public function filterRows(item:Object):Boolean {
            if(showAll)
                return true;
            if(item.messageVisible=="true")
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        public var showAll:Boolean;

        public function showAllMessages():void{

            showAll = true;
            filterResults();
        }
        public function hideMessages():void{
            showAll = false;
            filterResults();
        }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox>
    <component:EditMessage id="editMessage"  width="930" height="445"/>
    <mx:Panel id="messageListPanel" title="Message History" layout="vertical" width="930" height="196" horizontalAlign="left">

        <mx:DataGrid id="messageDataGrid" dataProvider="{modelLocator.notification.messageList}" 
                     width="910" height="139" enabled="true" mouseEnabled="true" editable="false"
                     rowCount="5" itemClick="{selectMessage()}">

            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Date Created" labelFunction="formatCreateDate" width="60"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="From" dataField="senderEmail" width="100"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Subject" dataField="subject" width="100"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Start Date" labelFunction="formatStartDate" width="60"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="End Date" labelFunction="formatEndDate" width="60" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Date Sent" labelFunction="formatSendDate" width="60" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Sender Netid" dataField="senderNetId" width="50" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Sender Name" dataField="senderName" width="80" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Message" dataField="message" width="100" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Message Id" dataField="id" width="10" />
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>              
    </mx:Panel>                 
</mx:VBox>
<mx:Button id="showMessagesBtn" x="786" y="452" label="Show All Messages" click="showAllMessages()"/>
<mx:Button id="hideMessagesBtn" x="665" y="452" label="Hide Messages" click="hideMessages()" />
```

Comment: That did it. And looking at it now, I can't believe it was that easy. Thanks @shaunhusain